# Best way to stream a youtube video on a desktop app

Tags: streaming, youtube

I want to make a desktop application which can play a youtube video, streaming it of course, which would be the easiest way to do it? 
Any language / library, I'm guessing maybe Adobe Air is the easiest way? I'm not very experienced with that but it should not be hard... Although I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: What programming language would be ideal?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If this desktop application is not intended to be portable, and you just need a fast hack, you can embed an ActiveX Internet Explorer component in a C++ winapi or C# .NET program, and then point the 'embedded' browser to the YouTube page you're looking for, or just an ad-hoc HTML page that just shows the video (using the embed video link from YouTube). This is fast (1-2 hours of work) and works, not very neat, though. It relies on the fact that the target machine is running Windows and has got the Flash plugin on Internet Explorer.

Comment: Interesting. I think this is one of the easiest approachs I found, what I thought though, was using javafx, which has a component for streaming a flv, that would make it easy, but I would need to learn javafx, which is not a big deal anyways.
I shall check which solution is better for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Java's JTextPane can display HTML.
[See here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0205.html)

I'd imagine you could adapt the code above easily enough so that it displays just the video frame.